# Swift dynamic tableview in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode7.2

I have been trying to add a tableview in my ViewController unfortunately no data is shown in my table view. **numberOfSectionsInTableView** ,  **numberOfRowsInSection** , **cellForRowAtIndexPath**  are not even getting called.I tried tableview inside ViewController as there is another controls like label ,  text field's and TableView underneath .Because of these label's and text fields I am unable to use a TableViewController. what I have done ...

1. Created a UIViewController and added controls like label , text fields etc.
2. From Object Library I dragged a TableView into my UIViewController.
3. To manage my data from server I created a Model

   ```
    class Model {

   var name : String
   var email : String

   init?(name : String , email : String)
   {
       self.name = name
       self.email = email
   } }
   ```
4. as I have dynamic data, for the cell I created a swift file under the Subclass UITableViewCell named **userinfoCell** and connected my labels(two label's inside TableViewCell one for username and another for email) to this class(userinfoCell).
5. Finally in my UIViewController I have added the following code to populate my Table View.

Inside my class definition I have initialised a global variable like this

```
var model = [Model]()
```

I have created a function that adds data to my model

```
 func loadMembers()
    {

        let member1 = Model(name: "Caprese Salad", email: "caprreswe@gmail.com")!

        let member2 = Model(name: "Capresed", email: "pepperoni@gmail.com")!



        model += [member1, member2]

    }
```

**on my ViewDidLoad I calls this function**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        loadMembers()
    }



override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int 
    {
       return 1
    }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Members", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! userinfoCell

        let member = model[indexPath.row]


        cell.MemberName.text = member.name
        cell.MemberEmail.text = member.email


        return cell
    }
```

But I am getting an Empty table view. What went wrong in my approach

how can I implement a dynamic UITableView inside UIViewController ???

Comment: have you set datasource and delegates of tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl drag from table view to View controller and set datasource and delegate

[image]

then call `self.tableView.reloadData()` in `loadMember()`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your loadMembers method like this,

```
func loadMembers()
{
    let member1 = Model(name: "Caprese Salad", email: "caprreswe@gmail.com")!

    let member2 = Model(name: "Capresed", email: "pepperoni@gmail.com")!

    model += [member1, member2]

    // reload the table view after modifying the data source.
    self.tableView.reloadData()   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold control and drag from tableview to view controller and set data source and delegate like this...

[image]